# insert a foreign key using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert with foreign key resident_id using prepared statement in table_complaints.

here is my picture of :

[image]

also i get the `$ides = $_POST["resident_id"];` in view page

[image]

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "myDb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST["submits"])){
    $comp_text = $_POST["comp"];
    $complaints = $_POST["complaints"];
    $ides =$_POST["resident_id"];

    $statementi = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($statementi, "INSERT INTO table_complaint (nature_of_complaints, status) 
     VALUES (?, ?) WHERE resident_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statementi, "ssi", $comp_text, $complaints);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statementi);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statementi);
}
 mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You can't have a `WHERE` clause in `INSERT`. This is for inserting *new* rows, why would it look for an existing row?

Comment: in my table there is resident_id foreign key , it will okay to leave blank?

Comment: No, you need to fill it in with the ID of the corresponding row in `table_resident`.

Comment: A foreign key has to match a row in the referenced table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert query is incorrect.

You can use this:

```
INSERT INTO table_complaint (resident_id,nature_of_complaints, status) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

and then bind the parameters:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statementi, "iss", $ides,$comp_text, $complaints);
```

Comment: Also needs another variable in the `bind_param` call.

Comment: yup adding it sir